# Slow Https response in Jetty

Tags: security, https, jetty

I'm using servlets 3 with jetty 8.1.1 and the SslContextFactory on an amazon ec2 machine (m1-small).

- The first HTTPS request from localhost (of the amazone machine) is about 150ms and further
  requests seem to get faster (down to ~40ms) but not as close as to
  the HTTP response time of only 20ms - why? Is encryption really that
  slow?
- Also when comparing HTTPS and HTTP from outside of the amazon cloud
  the difference gets even worse: HTTPS requests are at least 400ms
  slower!? How can that be? Is the encrypted content also bigger? And
  how can I debug it or make all faster?

Some more informations: all 'measurements' are unscientificly done via `time curl http://mydomain.com/ping` but are reproducable. Also there is an ec2 load balancer in between. I'm sure I've configured something wrong or there is a big misunderstanding from me. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

- update to 8.1.7
- check the time from localhost on the aws machine for reference
- check using the IP vs DNS, quite often those sorts of long pauses involve dns issues
- set your /etc/hosts to bypass a DNS look for host as a test as well
- -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG on the server side to enable debug, should help your correlate the roundtrip inside of jetty and compare to actual network results
- ssl decryption does incur some performance hit, hard to say that that would be all of your differences here though
- odds are this is not specific to jetty but something in the environment, which hopefully some bullet above will help steer you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate and report back!

Comment: hmmh when using the IP - how can I avoid the error: certificate subject name '*.domain.com' does not match target host name '<some IP>' ? Please see also my question update that the first bullet is already from an amazon machine. And what do you mean with the 4th point about the /etc/hosts and how would I do that?

Comment: when looking at the debug messages I get responses within 30-40ms starting with DBUG:oejs.Server:REQUEST /api on AsyncHttpConnection ending with DBUG:oejs.Server:RESPONSE /api 200 ... what does all the SSL NOT_HANDSHAKING mean?

Comment: puh and upgrading to 8.1.7 didn't help

Comment: Important question: Are ssl sessions enabled? If not, is allowRenegotiate=true the correct parameter to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I need to find out how to enable SSL sessions. For this I've created [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15946228/194609) as it is unclear how to turn on in jetty and how to handle on the client side